# Mac os Lombok installation in STS

Tags: eclipse, macos, lombok, sts

steps to install lombok in STS on mac os. I can't find any IDEs on your computer

[image]

Answer (score 28):

- Install STS
- Download the lombok.jar from https://projectlombok.org/download
- Double click on lombok.jar, then a window opens or run the cmd: java -jar lombok.jar or sudo java -jar lombok.jar
  [image]
- click specify location, go to Applications -> Spring tool suite -> contents -> Eclipse -> SpringToolSuite.ini, click open. see below image

[image]

- click install/update and restart your STS

Answer (score 9):

You can install any plugin using install new software..

```
STS--> help--> install new software

https://projectlombok.org/p2
```

[image]